Hash is not getting matched when stored using digest password
We are trying to integrate keycloak with geoserver DB. DB is storing users using digest password which cannot be reversed. I'm writing this code in keycloak SPI so that I'm able to login using custom provider database.
I'm trying to extract the salt from the stored password and then call digest method on it which is present in StandardByteDigester class. Since salt is first 16 bytes.
When I try to match both the hashes I don't see it matches. Please ignore the current hash of input password since it is 48 bytes. Even if we see in console the bytes from 16 onwards don't match since it should be.
snip..
try ( Connection c = DbUtil.getConnection(this.model)) {
    PreparedStatement st = c.prepareStatement("select password from users where name = ?");
    st.setString(1, username);
    st.execute();
    ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
    if ( rs.next()) {
        String pwd = rs.getString(1);
        log.info("pwd -> {}", pwd);
        // Instantiate SHA1HashProvider
        StandardByteDigester digester = new StandardByteDigester();
        digester.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");
        digester.setIterations(100000);
        digester.setSaltSizeBytes(16);
        digester.initialize();
        // Split the stored password into salt and hash
        String[] parts = pwd.split(":");

        byte[] decodedStoredPassword = Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[1].getBytes());

        // Extract the salt (first 16 bytes, as per the salt size set in digester)
        byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(decodedStoredPassword, 0, 16);

        // Extract the hash (remaining bytes)
        byte[] storedHash = Arrays.copyOfRange(decodedStoredPassword, 16, decodedStoredPassword.length);


        // Recompute the hash with the extracted salt
        byte[] recomputedHash = digester.digest(concatenate(
                toBytes(credentialInput.getChallengeResponse().toCharArray()), salt));
        log.info("stored hash n  len {} {}", storedHash, storedHash.length);
        log.info("recomputed hash n len  {} {}", recomputedHash, recomputedHash.length);
        boolean match =  Arrays.equals(storedHash, recomputedHash);
        log.info("do pwds match? -> {}", match);

        // Generate hash from the input password using SHA1HashProvider
        return Arrays.equals(storedHash, recomputedHash);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
catch(SQLException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Database error:" + ex.getMessage(),ex);
}

Logs

2024-08-22 10:53:49,253 INFO  [user.CustomUserStorageProvider] (executor-thread-3) recomputed hash n len  [-108, 52, 119, -9, -2, -74, 124, -71, 74, -90, 98, -65, 89, 30, -127, 119, 74, 124, 40, 126, 5, -5, 101, 101, 38, -32, -17, 107, 61, 55, 31, 44, 125, 69, -95, 36, -15, -100, 20, -102, 50, 69, 111, -107, 40, 53, 7, -77] 48

2024-08-22 10:53:49,254 INFO  [user.CustomUserStorageProvider] (executor-thread-3) do pwds match? -> false```

Can someone please help me get unstuck?

